# Copy data and keeping referencial integrity for new IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, foreign-keys

I need a tool or method that allows the transfer of data and automatically updates the foreign keys at the destination table.

The SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON/OFF is not what I'm looking for.

Example:

```
table master (id int identity, name char)
table slave (id int identity, master_id int, name char)
```

I would like to create a script like this:

```
insert into master(name) values ('master a')
insert into master(name) values ('master b')

insert into slave(master_id,name) values ( ?, 'slave aa')
insert into slave(master_id,name) values ( ?, 'slave bb')
insert into slave(master_id,name) values ( ?, 'slave cc')
insert into slave(master_id,name) values ( ?, 'slave dd')
```

When inserting the *slaves*, I would like to know what is the new value of the master_id, in order to keep the same relation as in the original table.

Comment: It sounds like you simply have two tables in a single database.  But the names "master" and "slave" are traditionally used when you're copying data from one database to another, as in replication.  Can you clarify?

Comment: It's not replication. The example tables could be named "Author" and "Book", for instance.

Comment: did you try my sproc? that should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@John Sansom: right on the money

@pv2008:

```
create proc InsertAndUpdate
@parentName varchar(255),
@childName varchar(255)

as
declare @newParentId int
insert into PARENT values (@parentName)
select @newParentId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

insert into CHILD values (@newParentId, @childName)
```

call this sproc every time you insert

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Identity columns within your tables, the function SCOPE_IDENTITY() will return the ID of the last inserted record. You can then use this as the foreign key for the secondary table.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Make sense?

Cheers, John

Answer (score 1):

If you use UniqueIdentifier (Guid) instead of int, then you don't need to change the ID values when you move them from one database to another.

Comment: Thanks, but this is legacy data - I can't change the schema.